# How to parse a string with pipes into an exec()?

Tags: c, parsing, pipe, fork

The idea is to be able to receive a char * command that will correspond to a list of commands that i'll need to execute. At the moment i already have a general structure to create all the forks and pipes needed, creating the respective File Descriptors and closing them, but now i need to actually fill the execlp() calls i'm making. The code looks like this:

```
int execute_commands(char * commands){

    int numPipes = ?;

    int numCommands = numPipes + 1;


    int pipe_fd[numPipes][2];



    if(pipe(pipe_fd[0]) < 0){

        perror("pipe[0]");
        exit(1);
    }


    if(fork() == 0){
        close(pipe_fd[0][0]);

        dup2(pipe_fd[0][1],1);
        close(pipe_fd[0][1]);

        execlp();

        _exit(1);
    }

    close(pipe_fd[0][1]);


    for(int i = 1; i<numPipes; i++){

        if(pipe(pipe_fd[i]) < 0){

        perror("Pipe error");
        exit(1);
        }

        if(fork() == 0){

            close(pipe_fd[i][0]);

            dup2(pipe_fd[i-1][0], 0);
            close(pipe_fd[i-1][0]);

            dup2(pipe_fd[i][1], 1);
            close(pipe_fd[i][1]);

            execlp();

            _exit(1);
        }

        close(pipe_fd[i-1][0]);
        close(pipe_fd[i][1]);
    }


    if(pipe(pipe_fd[0]) < 0){
        perror("pipe[0]");
        exit(1);
    }


    if(fork() == 0){
        int i = numPipes-1;
        dup2(pipe_fd[i][0],0);
        close(pipe_fd[i][0]);

        execlp();

        _exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< numCommands;i++){
        wait(NULL); 

    }
```

Basically the first and last process have different behaviours but all the ones inbetween these 2 are similar, thus the for loop creating the pipes and forks taking into consideration the number of pipes that are passed in the command. Now, imagining the commands passed are: "grep -v /etc/passwd/ | cut -f7 -d: | wc -l". How can i get the number of pipes, and after that, divide each command in their respective arguments to include them on the execlp()? I've hardcoded the example i'm giving  and it wrote on the std_out the same value that i get while simply running the commands on the shell so i assume the code structure i'm giving is somewhat correct and would work for any number of commands.

Comment: Use something like `strtok` to parse the string.

Comment: `execlp` can only be used when the number of arguments is known at compile time, so you're going to want `execvp` instead.